# Resolve ESLint error "no-unused-vars"

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, eslint

**The Error**

Module build failed because of the following eslint errors:

> Error 1: '**player**' is assigned a value but never used **no-unused-vars**
>
> Error 2: '**YT**' is not defined **no-undef**
>
> Error 3: '**onYouTubeIframeAPIReady**' is defined but never used  **no-unused-vars**

**The Code**

```
function videoInit() {
    // Initialise video
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // Initialise the player
    var player;

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }
    }
    
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { 
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            videoId: 'ScMzIvxBSi4',
            playerVars : {
                'mute' : 1,
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            },
        });
    }
}
```

**The Goal**

Resolving the **no-unused-vars** & **no-undef** errors.

The function call is not present in the local files but from the YouTube API as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference):

> `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` – The API will call this function when the page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player API, which enables you to then use the API on your page. Thus, this function might create the player objects that you want to display when the page loads.

It is possible to ignore the error **no-unused-vars** by using
`/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */`, but I am convinced there is a better approach to resolve these issues.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A separate `.eslintrc` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should be available as global variable (= property of `window` object). As it stands, it's just a local one, available within `videoInit()` - but not callable from outside. So ESLint is actually right on that point.

Use something similar to...

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
```

As for `player`, you only need this variable if you intend to use the returned value of `new YT.Player()` call (instance of player). In this particular case, you don't use it, hence the warning. Consider turning `videoInit` into a function that returns Promise (resolved with `player` value).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it resolved all issues.